# Tag for different types of poker (collective)

Tags: feature-request, tags

I would suggest having a tag with a name such as "Poker-Styles" or simply "Styles" to direct people to questions related to the different poker games that are out there. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: It is not clear to me from your post what thus tag would encompass. Can you give some examples?

Comment: for questions like "what different types of poker are there?" and "how do the rules differ between types of poker?"

Answer (score 1):

You can already just name the type of poker directly, and then, just search for the variant you're interested in.

For example, [nlhe](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlhe),[no-limit](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-limit)[omaha-hi-lo](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/omaha-hi-lo), or stake levels and type [nl200](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nl200)

Specific is preferred over "collective".

Comment: ah no problem cheers :) just my only problem was that i recently asked a question about what different types of poker there were so if people did not know the names of other games they might not know how to tag their question

Comment: If they don't know the name of the game they're playing... they've come to the right place :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Variant` will be a better Tag.

Yes, there is nlhe and omaha-hilo. But there's not PLO, Razz, 7-Stud, HORSE, and so on.

For the most common variant, some tags can be created (`HORSE`, `PLO`), but a generic tag as `Variant` will be usefull.